# OCR Form Labelling Tool model id not found by GetCustomModelsAsync

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

So, I set up the OCR Form Labelling Tool and got everything to work great, and after running training, I get a model id. Now I want to use that model when using the Form Recognizer client library for .NET. Again, got the sample working fine. Both point to the same Form Recognizer service and Azure Blob storage.

However, when I run the GetCustomModelsAsync, it doesn't return the model created in the OCR Form Labelling Tool, and if I copy the Model guid from the Labelling tool, GetExtractedKeysAsync cannot find the model (it does find one that isn't the same, so it is working). Same subscription key, same endpoint.

How to I use the model created in the OCR Form Labelling Tool in the .Net client library. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What .NET SDK version are you using ? Only the new .NET SDK release supports the Form Recognizer v2.0 release and the train with labels models. It is located here

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/formrecognizer/Azure.AI.FormRecognizer

dotnet add package Azure.AI.FormRecognizer --version 1.0.0-preview.2

Thanks, 
Neta - MSFT

Comment: Great. That was the issue - an outdated SDK. Thanks for your help.